# Mean of grouped data using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to use Pandas to calculate hourly averages from one minute data for a fairly large dataset.
My dataset is stored as a .csv, and looks like:

```
,timestamp_local,pm25
0,5/30/2022 16:59,2.2802
1,5/30/2022 16:58,2.7055
2,5/30/2022 16:57,1.6602
3,5/30/2022 16:56,1.5924
4,5/30/2022 16:55,2.2792
5,5/30/2022 16:54,2.2219
```

I attempted to read the .csv file as a Pandas DataFrame and then store the hourly means in a new DataFrame that I will export:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('extracted_data.csv')
df['timestamp_local'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_local'])

df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='timestamp_local'), 'pm25']).mean()

print(df1)
```

After executing this script, I am left with the minute data grouped by it's respective hour:

```
timestamp_local     pm25       unnamed: 0      
2022-04-30 17:00:00 0.8766     42917.0
                    0.9124     42913.0
                    0.9647     42893.0
                    0.9842     42883.0
                    1.0974     42894.0
...                                ...
2022-05-30 16:00:00 3.0069        43.0
                    3.1727        40.0
                    3.2482        30.0
                    3.3628        42.0
                    4.5797        13.0
```

My goal is to eliminate the minute data altogether so I would just have the timestamp and the calculated hourly average, but I am unsure how to go about this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this? With a pandas pipeline you should be able to stack grouping and resampling methods.

```
df1 = df.groupby('pm25']).resample('H').mean()
```

### EDIT

I forgot to add that in order to resample, you must set your timestamp to the index. I reproduced your example accordingly

```
import pandas as pd

# I used index_col to make sure that it doesnt use the index as a data column
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col=0)
df['timestamp_local'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_local'])

# Here we set the index to the timestamp column. 
# The inplace parameter overwrite the index in the object `df`
df.set_index('timestamp_local', inplace=True)
results = df.groupby('pm25').resample('H').mean()
results
```

The output is

```
                              pm25
pm25   timestamp_local            
1.5924 2022-05-30 16:00:00  1.5924
1.6602 2022-05-30 16:00:00  1.6602
2.2219 2022-05-30 16:00:00  2.2219
2.2792 2022-05-30 16:00:00  2.2792
2.2802 2022-05-30 16:00:00  2.2802
2.7055 2022-05-30 16:00:00  2.7055
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, thank you for your response.

I tried using the code you suggested and ended up with a TypeError: "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'"

I apologize if I'm overlooking something obvious, I'm fairly new to Python and this is my first time working with the Pandas module.

Comment: Hi there, I created a better example, this should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('extracted_data.csv')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_local'])

df1 = df.groupby([df.index.day, df.index.hour]).mean()

df1.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

This gave me the data grouped by day & hour with the calculated hourly mean of the 'pm25' parameter:

```
timestamp_local timestamp_local      pm25
1               0                    4.917292
                1                    2.976207
                2                    15.244288
                3                    5.802312
                4                    6.185230
...                                     ...        ...
30              19                   2.388808
                20                   1.300867
                21                   2.053445
                22                   7.007275
                23                   10.163283
```